# Laços de repetição com AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, localstorage

Estou tentando listar os dados de dois laços `ng-repeat` do meu código, porém 1 deles não está funcionando.

No caso, estou usando:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills col-md-2" >
  <li ng-repeat="g in formulario.grupos">
      <a data-target="{{g.titulo}}" data-toggle="tab">{{g.titulo}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content col-md-10" style="border:#000; border-radius:5px;">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="" ng-repeat="c in g.campos" >
      <input type="" ng-model="c.campo" name="" value="" class="form-control" > <!--ng-repeat="campo in g.campos"-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Meu problema está aí. O primeiro laço traz os formulários (grupos) e o segundo lista os inputs destes formulários (campos)

Essa informação é recuperada via localStorage de um JSON.

Comment: Mostra a controller que vc montou pra povoar essa li ai, talvez seja lá o problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que me parece é que o teu segundo `ng-repeat` vai buscar informação a uma variavel `g` que só deverá existir dentro do elemento a que está ligado o primeiro `ng-repeat`.

Talvez não seja o que pretendes, mas assim já não deverá dar-te problemas:

```
<ul class="nav nav-stacked nav-pills col-md-2" >
  <li ng-repeat="g in formulario.grupos">
    <a data-target="{{g.titulo}}" data-toggle="tab">{{g.titulo}}</a>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content col-md-10" style="border:#000; border-radius:5px;">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="" ng-repeat="c in g.campos" >
        <input type="" ng-model="c.campo" name="" value="" class="form-control" > <!--ng-repeat="campo in g.campos"-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Isto, porque dentro do `<li ng-repeat="g in formulario.grupos">...</li>` a variável `g` existe.

Diz-me se resultou, e se pelo menos te levou à solução. Boa sorte ;)

Comment: Funcionou Rik! Obrigado :)